# How to place a label on a single row/ on a single line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Two labels get separated by a line. I need to fix that(Look at First Name, Last Name)
[image]

```
<section id="names">
    <B>First Name:</B><input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
    <B>Last Name:</B><input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname">
</section>
```

I don't know if they will help but here I wrote some useless css for it

```
#names {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: you mention `labels` yet you have not actually used `label` tags to control this. If you want them on separate lines use `flex-direction:column;`

Comment: Try `width: max-content;`

Comment: You shouldn't be using floats with flex. Really, you shouldn't be using floats _at all_. They're an old technique with few legitimate modern uses. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox for how to align content properly.

Comment: In the natural state they(firstName & lastName) are placed on a line. unless `#name` have a finite width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
#names {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: left;
}

label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<section id="names">
    <!--use proper tags-->
    <label for="name">
       <b>First Name:</b>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
    <label for="surname">
       <b>Last Name:</b>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want. I think you want them to be seperate by a new line. If you change the `flex-direction` to "*column*" instead of "*row*". It will divide them by space instead of being up against eachother.

```css
#names {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="names">
    <B>First Name:</B><input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
    <B>Last Name:</B><input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname">
</section>
```

Comment: I think I did not write more concisely. What I want is for the label to not get chopped into two rows/lines, but rather stay on the same line. Like this, "1)    First Name", and not "1)  First      2) Name"

Comment: if that is the case, then adding `white-space: nowrap` should fix it

Comment: like @jade answer